# I changed my VNC password before, and now I forgot it. How do I reset my password?

Tags: vnc

I tried using vncpasswd but that did not work, any ideas?

Comment: `that did not work` .... in what way did it fail? because I'd have thought `vncpasswd` is how you set the `vnc password`

Comment: And which VNC do you use? IIRC RealVNC has additional methods of storing/using passwords that are not compatible with vncpassword

Comment: This is not a question belonging to Raspberry Pi. You should better ask at https://superuser.com/